# How to sort a list of my objects

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting

I've been coding for hours now trying to finish my assignment. Now that I am done, I would like to add a method that sorts the value of the customers. So that customer 2 comes on top and 5 last. How do I do that?

Here is the code for the first class:

```
public class Customer {

    private int customerNumber;
    private int purchases;
    private int shippingCost;
    private int productPrice;

    public int getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(int productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public int getPurchases() {
        return purchases;
    }

    public Customer(int purchases, int shippingCost, int productPrice) {
        this.purchases = purchases;
        this.shippingCost = shippingCost;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public void setPurchases(int purchases) {
        this.purchases = purchases;
    }

    public int getShippingCost() {
        return shippingCost;
    }

    public void setShippingCost(int shippingCost) {
        this.shippingCost = shippingCost;
    }

    protected int calculateValue() {
        int value=purchases*(productPrice-shippingCost);
        return value;
    }

    public int getCustomerNumber() {
        return customerNumber;
    }

    public void setCustomerNumber(int customerNumber) {
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }
```

The second class:

```
public class Subscriber extends Customer{

    private int years;
    private int fee;

    public Subscriber(int purchases, int shippingCost, int productPrice) {
        super(purchases, shippingCost,  productPrice);
    }

    public Subscriber(int purchases, int shippingCost, 
            int productPrice,int _years,int _fee) {
        super(purchases, shippingCost, productPrice);
        years=_years;
        fee=_fee;
    }

    public int getYears() {
        return years;
    }

    public void setYears(int years) {
        this.years = years;
    }

    public int getFee() {
        return fee;
    }

    public void setFee(int fee) {
        this.fee = fee;
    }

    protected int calculateSubscriptionValue() {
        return years*fee;
    }

    protected int calculateValue(){
        int value=super.calculateValue();   
        value+=calculateSubscriptionValue();
        return value;
    }
```

Third class:

```
public class BusinessSubscriber extends Subscriber{

    public BusinessSubscriber(int purchases, int shippingCost, int productPrice, int _years, int _fee) {
        super(purchases, shippingCost, productPrice, _years, _fee);
    }
    private double supportCost;
    private double supportTime;

    public double getSupportCost() {
        return supportCost;
    }
    public void setSupportCost(double supportCost) {
        this.supportCost = supportCost;
    }
    public double getSupportTime() {
        return supportTime;
    }
    public void setSupportTime(double supportTime) {
        this.supportTime = supportTime;
    }

    //override method: // skriv över den // problem med denna metod. uträkningsfel
    protected int calculateValue(){
        int value=super.calculateValue();   
        value+=calculateSubscriptionValue() - calculateSubscriptionValue();
        return value;
    }
}
```

Last and the main class:

```
public class printValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Unsorted version without DataStructure");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        BusinessSubscriber num1 = new BusinessSubscriber(3, 33, 99, 8, 78); 

        num1.setCustomerNumber(1);

        num1.setPurchases(3);
        num1.setShippingCost(33);
        num1.setYears(8);
        num1.setSupportTime(2);
        num1.setProductPrice(99);
        num1.setFee(78);
        num1.setSupportCost(25);
        System.out.println("Customer number: " + num1.getCustomerNumber() + " is worth " + num1.calculateValue() + "!");

        BusinessSubscriber num2 = new BusinessSubscriber (0, 0, 99, 18, 78);

        num2.setCustomerNumber(2);

        num2.setPurchases(0);
        num2.setShippingCost(0);
        num2.setYears(18);
        num2.setSupportTime(7);

        num2.setProductPrice(99);
        num2.setFee(78);
        num2.setSupportCost(25);

        System.out.println("Customer number: " + num2.getCustomerNumber() + " is worth " + num2.calculateValue() + "!");

        BusinessSubscriber num3 = new BusinessSubscriber (0, 0, 99, 8, 78);

        num3.setCustomerNumber(3);

        num3.setPurchases(0);
        num3.setShippingCost(0);
        num3.setYears(8);
        num3.setSupportTime(0);

        num2.setProductPrice(99);
        num2.setFee(78);
        num2.setSupportCost(25);

        System.out.println("Customer number: " + num3.getCustomerNumber() + " is worth " + num3.calculateValue() + "!");

        //  int purchases, int shippingCost, int productPrice, int _years, int _fee 

        Subscriber num4 = new Subscriber (12, 33, 99, 5, 78);

        num4.setCustomerNumber(4);

        num4.setPurchases(12);
        num4.setShippingCost(33);
        num4.setYears(5);

        num4.setProductPrice(99);
        num4.setFee(78);

        System.out.println("Customer number: " + num4.getCustomerNumber() + " is worth " + num4.calculateValue() + "!");

        Customer num5 = new Customer (8, 33, 99);

        num5.setCustomerNumber(5);

        num5.setPurchases(8);
        num5.setShippingCost(33);
        num5.setProductPrice(99);

        System.out.println("Customer number: " + num5.getCustomerNumber() + " is worth " + num5.calculateValue() + "!");

        // sortera efter calculatevalue metoden i businesssubsriber
}
```

The output of the code:

```
Customer number: 1 is worth 822!
Customer number: 2 is worth 1404!
Customer number: 3 is worth 624!
Customer number: 4 is worth 1182!
Customer number: 5 is worth 528!
```

I would like customer number 2 to be on top and 5 last, i.e sort them. How do I do that? Thank you.

I tried this, but is that enough?

```
Integer [] sort = {num1.calculateValue(), num2.calculateValue(), num3.calculateValue(), num4.calculateValue(), num5.calculateValue()};

List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(sort);

Collections.sort(l1);
System.out.println("Values sorted: " + l1);
```

But a more efficient way would be to put it all in a map, loop through it and then print it. How do I do that?

Also, I tried to edit the text as much as I can so it does not look messy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sorting your customers based on calculateValue() may b you can do like this:

```
Map sortedCustomer= new TreeMap();
sortedCustomer.put(num1.calculateValue(),num1);
sortedCustomer.put(num2.calculateValue(),num2);
sortedCustomer.put(num3.calculateValue(),num3);
sortedCustomer.put(num4.calculateValue(),num4);
sortedCustomer.put(num5.calculateValue(),num5);
//sortedCustomer is in ascending order...reverse it
sortedCustomerDescending =(TreeSet)sortedCustomer.descendingSet();
//get entrySet
  Set set = sortedCustomerDescending.entrySet();
  // Get an iterator
  Iterator i = set.iterator();
  // Display elements
  while(i.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
  //print the entries
     System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
     System.out.println(me.getValue());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to sort in descending order.

You need to pass implement a [Comaprator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and pass it to [Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) method along with a List holding the objects you want to sort.

Something liek this should do it

```
public void testSort() {
    List<Customer> cL = Arrays.asList(new Customer(1, 822), 
            new Customer(2, 1404), 
            new Customer(3, 624), 
            new Customer(4, 1182), 
            new Customer(5, 528));
    Collections.sort(cL, new Comparator<Customer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
            return o2.getCalc() - o1.getCalc();
        }
    });

    for( Customer c : cL) {
        System.out.println("Customer number: " + c.getCustomerNumber() 
                + " is worth " + c.getCalc() + "!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Customer number: 2 is worth 1404!
Customer number: 4 is worth 1182!
Customer number: 1 is worth 822!
Customer number: 3 is worth 624!
Customer number: 5 is worth 528!
```

For simplicity I have added a filed `calc` in `Customer` itself, you probably want to implement Comparator for the `BusinessSubscriber` class as the the value you are looking for sorting with comes from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Customer class should implement Comparable interface

```
public class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>{
```

You should override its compareTo method

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Customer cus) {
int calculatedValue = cus.calculateValue();
return calculatedValue - this.calculateValue();
}
```

Finally in your PrintValue class, add those customers to ArrayList and use Collections.sort

```
ArrayList<Customer> custList = new ArrayList<>();
custList.add(num1);
custList.add(num2);
custList.add(num3);
custList.add(num4);
custList.add(num5);

Collections.sort(custList);

for (Iterator iterator = custList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) iterator.next();
    System.out.println("Customer number: " + customer.getCustomerNumber() + " is worth " + customer.calculateValue() + "!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of objects, you can sort it with [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)).

Stupid example (not compiled or run):

```
Collections.sort(listOfUsers, new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
        return Integer.compare(u1.getAge(), u2.getAge());
    }
});
```

This comparison may not be exactly what you need to do, but you get the idea :-)